# control may reach end non void function

Tags: ios

Мне нужно обратиться к `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `через switch`, но выбивает ошибку:

> control may reach end non void function

Такая ошибка выбивает, когда я забуду поставить `return`, потому я думаю, что надо что-то возвратить, но я не знаю что. `return [indexPath.section]` не подходит

```
- (UITableViewCell* )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingSwitchCell" owner:self options:nil];
            SettingSwitchCell* cell = (SettingSwitchCell* ) [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.switchLabel.text = [_array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            return cell;
        }
        if (indexPath.row < 2) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingLabelCell" owner:self options:nil];
            SettingLabelCell* cell = (SettingLabelCell* ) [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.settingLabel.text = [_array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            return cell;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: Возвращайте ноль и проверяйте на вызывающей стороне что вернули не ноль. Но вообще это вам решать что должна возвращать функция в каком случае.

Comment: Можно вернуть ноль. Можно выкинуть Exception, если аргументы не удовлетворяющие перечисленным `case` и перечисленным `if` (`indexPath.row > 2`) НИКОГДА не должны попасть в функцию, и если попали, значит еще раньше что-то пошло не так.

Comment: return 0 подошло, но не понимаю. как оно работает, почему ноль?

Comment: @RZzin почитайте книги по C, в особенности тему по указателям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего будет вернуть пустой указатель в конце метода

```
return nil;
```

Если хотите больше подробностей о том, что происходит: Xcode пытается быть полезным и указывает на то, что существует возможность дойти до конца этого метода и ничего не вернуть, хотя в нем обязательно должно присутствовать возвращаемое значение. Произойти такое может, если, например, в таблице есть секция 1 и так далее.
Если вы точно знаете, что в таблице может быть только одна секция - уберите switch совсем, он не нужен. Если в таблице может быть больше одной секции, но по какой то причине вы не хотите их заполнять, можно создать ячейки с текстом, объясняющий почему эта ячейка пустая.

Comment: на самом деле, есть 3 секции,  просто на момент публикации я их еще не указал

Большое спасибо за такой полезный ответ. Вы как всегда в помощь)

Comment: @RZzin, обратите внимание, у вас и в `case 0` можно дойти до конца ничего не вернув, если `indexPath.row > 2`